# Как пишется "не делала""?

Tags: правописание

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как правильно писать "не делала",  слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 2):

Добавка к ответу Artemyx: за исключением случаев, в которых "не" - часть образующего слова, без которого формы нет (как "ненавидеть") или часть корня (как "нести").

Answer (score 0):

"Не" с глаголами -- раздельно.